# Maven private dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, build-process

Is there a way to specify private dependency for a project that will not be visible to others?

What I'm trying to achieve is pretty much similar to what exclusion does, but with one slight difference - user should not be aware of that dependency at all and, thus, won't have to use this exclusion explicitly.

And if this is not possible (which, most likely, is true), then is there any particular reason why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. When you say `private dependencies` do you mean `jar's` you have written..?

Comment: Would using the `provided` scope for your dependencies meet your requirements? Using this scope means that the dependency is "only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive." http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Comment: @user2339071 Yes, "homemade" jars or some third-party libraries.

Comment: @DB5 You're right - the provided scope will do pretty much what exclusion does.

Comment: As the question is written neither `provided` nor `optional` fulfils the requirements. OP asks neither about a dependency that is provided by a app container, nor a dependency that is only available sometimes. The question text is about a dependency that is distributed with the module, but that is not visible to clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional dependencies sound like what you want. Mark a dependency as `optional` and you'll have it when you build, but users won't automatically have that library included as a transitive dependency.

See [Maven - Optional Dependencies and Dependency Exclusions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) for more details.

'provided' is not the ideal solution here; that means that a dependency *is* required, but that it will be provided by any user of your artifact. 'optional' means that the dependency is only required for some functionality.

Comment: As the question is written neither `provided` nor `optional` fulfils the requirements. OP asks neither about a dependency that is provided by a app container, nor a dependency that is only available sometimes. The question text is about a dependency that is distributed with the module, but that is not visible to clients.